# Datos duplicados

Tags: postgresql

tengo una consulta si es que alguien me puede ayudar, resulta que realizo una consulta en postgresql y me lista, pero en dicho resultado tengo datos duplicados.

La consulta es la siguiente

```
    Select C.cod_storbox AS cod_storbox,
       C.fec_cierre as fec_cierre, 
       C.caja_id, 
       C.us_rut,
       carpeta.car_ruc AS car_ruc,
       TRIM(usuario.us_nombre) ||' '|| TRIM(usuario.us_apaterno) as nombre,
       carpeta.bod_id AS car_bodega
FROM cajas_cerradas AS C, usuario, carpeta
WHERE --cast(C.fec_cierre as date)  between cast('2020-12-02' as date) and cast('2020-12-15' as date) 
      cast(carpeta.car_fingreso as date)  between cast('01-01-2021' as date) and cast('20-01-2021' as date) 
      and C.us_rut = '0013488910-1'
      and C.us_rut = usuario.us_rut
      and cast(carpeta.cas_id as integer) = C.caja_id
      and C.sec_id = carpeta.sec_id
      and carpeta.ecar_crr = 2
      and cod_storbox != ''
      order by fec_cierre
```

como resultado obtengo:

```
"TCSM68000009"||"2021-01-05"||4||"0013488910-1"||"1900144431-2"
"TCSM68000009"||"2021-01-05"||4||"0013488910-1"||"1801194862-2"
"TCSM68000000"||"2021-01-05"||11||"0013488910-1"||"1901241097-5"
"TCSM68000000"||"2021-01-05"||11||"0013488910-1"||"2000752570-3"
"TCSM68020785"||"2021-01-05"||18||"0013488910-1"||"2000403271-4"
```

Mi pregunta es como hacer que de los datos repetidos solo quede uno, estuve viendo ROW_NUMBER(), pero no pude implementarlo.

el resultado que quiero es:

```
"TCSM68000009"||"2021-01-05"||4||"0013488910-1"||"1900144431-2"
"TCSM68000000"||"2021-01-05"||11||"0013488910-1"||"1901241097-5"
"TCSM68020785"||"2021-01-05"||18||"0013488910-1"||"2000403271-4"
```

Comment: La consulta que indicas tiene siete campos de salida. La salida de ejemplo tiene 5. Complicado entender lo que quieres hacer. Tampoco es claro en el ejemplo cuál es el criterio para filtrar los duplicados por el primer campo.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que puedes hacer, es que puedes eliminar los datos que se duplican dejando únicamente el que necesitas, para ello lo puedes hacer con el siguiente script

```
DELETE FROM tu_tabla a USING (
         SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, a.cod_storbox
           FROM tu_tabla
           GROUP BY a.cod_storbox HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
         ) b
         WHERE a.cod_storbox= b.cod_storbox
         AND a.ctid <> b.ctid
```

o bien, si el registro no se puede eliminar, te recomiendo que el resultado lo guardes en una tabla temporal y esta le aplicas el anterior script y te va a devolver la información como la necesitas

Answer (score -1):

usa este patrón para eliminar registros duplicados y dejar registros únicos en PostgreSQL. Funciona perfectamente. Este patrón lo encontré en https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/
Donde viene explicado a detalle más otras 2 variantes.
En el WHERE pueden poner el número de campos que necesiten para cumplir el criterio.
Espero les sirva. Saludos:

```
DELETE FROM
    mi_tabla a
        USING mi_tabla b 
/*la tabla "a" es la misma que tabla "b"*/
WHERE
    a.id < b.id 
/*Esta primera condición es obligatoria para dejar sólo el id más "antiguo" de entre todos los duplicados*/
    AND a.campo_1 = b.campo_1;
/*poner aquí el resto de los criterios de comparación*/
```

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio, pero la pregunta era sobre como eliminar los duplicados del resultado del SELECT. Por lo que he visto en el enlace, DELETE FROM borra los registros de la tabla. Son dos cosas completamente diferentes!